# Using pcolormesh with 3 one dimensional arrays in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to use pcolormesh to plot 3 one dimensional arrays filled with coordinates and values. The arrays below are simply examples, yet they follow the same principle. I have 3 arrays, one for the x coordinate, one for the y coordinate, and one for their value (or z). Each index corresponds to a location. Index of 0 corresponds to x of 1, y of 1 and z of 6. This goes on for all indexes.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
y = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
z = [6,2,3,5,8,2,3,2,4,2,3,6,7,3,3,2]
plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(x,y,z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I've also tried...

```
x = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
y = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
z = [6,2,3,5,8,2,3,2,4,2,3,6,7,3,3,2]
N = np.sqrt(len(x))
N = int(N)
np.reshape(x,(N,N))
np.reshape(y,(N,N))
np.reshape(z,(N,N))
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,c=z)
plt.show()
```

Nothing seems to be working. Send Help

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt was the right direction - except for two things:

- `np.reshape` *returns* the reshaped array, it is not *applied* to the array parameter.
- *if* you want to specify the third kwarg by name - it's a capital `C` not a lower case `c`

So this works:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
y = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
z = [6,2,3,5,8,2,3,2,4,2,3,6,7,3,3,2]
x = np.reshape(x,(4, 4))
y = np.reshape(y,(4, 4))
z = np.reshape(z,(4, 4))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
```

However, cleaner to read perhaps would be sth like this:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(range(4), range(4))
z = [6, 2, 3, 5, 8, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6, 7, 3, 3, 2]
z = np.reshape(z, (4, 4))
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
```

That's the use case that `meshgrid` was made for.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I had one more question, though. Whenever I try and use this, it returns 9 grids instead of 16. On the same lines, only the z values which have coordinates within that 3 by 3 alter the color of the colormesh.

Comment: That's because of the interpolation between the grid points. With `pcolormesh` the coordinates lie on the grid and the color you see is the area inbetween. The default interpolation is afair like a step function, but you can choose another interpolation method by `shading='gouraud'`. If you want a visualization where each color is represented by cell, you might want to look at `plt.imshow`. See also https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you for your help!