# Make a 2d histogram show if a certain value is above or below average?

Tags: python, arrays, histogram, colorbar

I made a 2d histogram of two variables(x and y) and each of them are long, 1d arrays. I then calculated the average of x in each bin and want to make the colorbar show how much each x is above or below average in the respective bin.

So far I have tried to make a new array, z, that contains the values for how far above/below average each x is. When I try to use this with pcolormesh I run into issues that it is not a 2-D array. I also tried to solve this issue by following the solution from this problem ([Using pcolormesh with 3 one dimensional arrays in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52710519/using-pcolormesh-with-3-one-dimensional-arrays-in-python)). The length of each array (x, y and z) are equal in this case and there is a respective z value for each x value.

My overall goal is to just have the colorbar not dependent on counts but to have it show how much above/below average each x value is from the average x of the bin. I suspect that it may make more sense to just plot x vs. z but I do not think that would fix my colorbar issue.

Comment: code, we need code + sample data !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LoneWanderer mentioned some sample code would be useful; however let me make an attempt at what you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10000
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N) # Generating x and y data (you will already have this)

# Histogram data
xbins = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
ybins = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
hdata, xedges, yedged = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xbins, ybins))

# compute the histogram average value and the difference
hdataMean = np.mean(hdata)
hdataRelDifference = (hdata - hdataMean) / hdataMean

# Plot the relative difference
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cax = ax.imshow(hdataRelDifference)
fig.colorbar(cax, ax=ax)
```

If this is not what you intended, hopefully there are enough pieces here to adapt it for your needs.